# angularjs orderBy with multiple functions, how to reverse?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat iterating over a set of objects that requires some functions to extract the values I want to sort by.

My ng-repeat looks like this:

```
ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy: [sortFnOne, sortFnTwo, ...]"
```

What I am having trouble with, is I would like sortFnOne to be reversed.  These are extracting strings that I can't access using simple attributes as it's doing some conversion on the data to produce these values that I am trying to sort by.

If it were simple I know I would just do:

```
ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy: ['-id', 'name', '-status', ...]"
```

If these functions were just returning booleans I could just ! the return value to get the result I wanted, but some of these are returning strings, and some are returning dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Have you considered simply writing a custom filter instead? It's a shame in your case that the `reverse` flag (i.e. second argument) offered `orderBy` only applies to the entire array.

Comment: I second @miqid regarding the filter. You might want to have a look at this link. It may help you. http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

Comment: Post a plunker or fiddle with a minimum example, then it's easier to help

Comment: Example would be good. It will probably boil down to having a custom filter

Comment: An example would be: Idea is my model. Idea has raterCount, totalStarCount and creationDate as model attributes. Average Rating would be then totalStarCount / raterCount, which is not saved in Database. I would like to sort the ideas by creationDate (to both sides) and as 2. criterion by averageRating (just Reverse).

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this limitation myself... there is no way to invert an ordering done by a function with the `orderBy` filter.

As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to reproduce this kind of compound ordering with direction (order by 'A' ascending then by 'B' descending) in the native JavaScript API.

`Array.prototype.sort` offers basic ordering via a compare function (see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for details) but no way to easily switch sort order (reverse) without writing another compare function and it offers no solution for compound ordering. What we need is a compact notation to specify the direction and priority of multiple orderings.

I wrote this helper some time ago to help with this very problem.

```
  var orderByAgeThenName = new OrderByBuilder().asc(getAge).asc(getName).build();
  var friendsByAgeThenName = orderByAgeThenName(friends);

  var orderByNameThenAge = new OrderByBuilder().desc(getName).asc(getAge).build();
  var friendsByNameThenAge = orderByNameThenAge(friends);
```

This is not an angular filter, so just wrap it in a controller method and call it from your template. Or, simply apply the ordering to your array inside the controller.

I guess this could be adapted to an angular filter...

Runnable Sample:

```js
angular.module('orderByExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var friends =
    [{name:'Jon', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
     {name:'Zach', phone:'555-2276', age:7},                     
     {name:'Zach', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
     {name:'Zach', phone:'555-9276', age:13},           
     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];

  function getName(f){
    return f.name;
  }

  function getAge(f){
    return f.age;
  }
  
  var orderByName       = new OrderByBuilder().desc(getName).build();
  var orderByNameAndAge = new OrderByBuilder().desc(getName).asc(getAge).build();

  $scope.friendLists = [
    {label:'Not Ordered', friends: friends},
    {label:'Name DESC', friends: orderByName(friends)},
    {label:'Name DESC, Age ASC', friends: orderByNameAndAge(friends)}
  ];
  
}]);




function OrderByBuilder(orderings){
  var _orderings = [];

  return {
    asc: function(fn){
      addOrdering(true,fn);
      return this;
    },
    desc: function(fn){
      addOrdering(false,fn);
      return this;
    },
    build: build
  };

  function addOrdering(asc,fn){
    _orderings.push({
      getterFn: fn,
      asc: asc
    });
    return this;
  }

  function build(){
    var compare = _orderings.reverse().reduce(function(nextComparer, ordering){
      return getComparerFn(ordering, nextComparer);
    },null);

    return function(xs){
      return xs.slice().sort(compare);
    };
  }

  // a comparerFn has the following signature:
  //  function(a: obj, b: obj): int

  function getComparerFn(ordering, nextComparer){
    var next = nextComparer || function(a,b){ return 0; };
    var getVal = ordering.getterFn;

    return function(a,b){
      var aVal = getVal(a);
      var bVal = getVal(b);
      if(aVal < bVal){ return ordering.asc ? -1 :  1; }
      if(aVal > bVal){ return ordering.asc ?  1 : -1; }
      return next(a,b);
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="orderByExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="friendList in friendLists" class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>{{friendList.label}}</h4>
        
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="friend in friendList.friends">
            <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows you to provide a comparator function as the third argument to orderBy. This comparator function gives you the power to specify your own ordering.

Here is a [Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/GfEGRHfDkQ3vcngBa0Ao/) that demonstrates dynamic complex sorting. It loads 100 records from a JSON file and originally sorts the names first by Last Name, then by First Name. When you sort by something other than Last Name, it uses Last Name and First Name to break ties. However, while the sort order on the primary field may be reversed, the example demonstrated will still sort Last Name and First name in ascending order.

```js
$scope.compareData = function(left, right) {
  function compareValues(valueLeft, valueRight) {
    var valueReturn;
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(valueLeft)) && !isNaN(parseInt(valueRight))) {
      valueReturn =
        ((valueLeft * 1) < (valueRight * 1)
        ? -1
        : ((valueLeft * 1) > (valueRight * 1) ? 1 : 0));
    } else {
      valueReturn = valueLeft.toString().localeCompare(valueRight.toString());
    }
    return valueReturn;
  }
  var dataReturn = 0;
  if (typeof right === "undefined") {
    dataReturn = 1;
  } else if (typeof left === "undefined") {
    dataReturn = -1;
  } else {
    var valuesLeft = left.value.split(",");
    var valuesRight = right.value.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; (i < valuesLeft.length) && (dataReturn === 0); ++i) {
      dataReturn = compareValues(valuesLeft[i], valuesRight[i]);
      dataReturn *= ($scope.sortReverse && (i > 0)) ? -1 : 1;
    }
  }
  return dataReturn;
}
```

The above is the function used for the comparator in the linked Plunk. Note at the end that reversing the sort on a field is as simple as multiplying the result by -1.