# orderBy sorting by string AND integer on ng-repeat in angular 1.5.0

Tags: angularjs

I've got an angular 1.5 project, and upgrading isn't really an option right now.  I'm trying to simply sort a collection of items such as:

```
"Bar #1 // #1A", 
"Foo #1 // #1A", 
"Foo #1 // #1B", 
"Foo #2 // #2", 
"Foo #2 // #10",
"Foo #10 // #1", etc
```

...

[Angular 1.5.0's docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy) say:

> Array: An array of function or string predicates. The first predicate in the array is used for sorting, but when two items are equivalent, the next predicate is used.

So, I first tried just doing:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: sortFunc"
```

where the sort function does:

```
scope.sortFunc = function (item) {                                                                                                                                   
  var replaced = item.name.replace(/(\d+)/g, ',\$1');                                                                                                                
  return replaced.split(',').map(function (fragment) {                                                                                                                          
    var number = parseInt(fragment, 10);                                                                                                                            
    return number ? Number(number) : fragment;
  });
};
```

I am returning an array such as ["Bar #", 1, " // #", 1, "A"].  So I thought this would work exactly as they described..  When two items are equivalent, the next is used.

But I guess it doesn't support a function returning an array..........  It needs to be an array of functions, but I have no way to generate an array of functions based off of a string's components.....................................................

So is there any way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Example using multiple functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640330/angularjs-orderby-with-multiple-functions-how-to-reverse

Comment: If it is a function it needs to return a single value that can then be used internally by `sort()`. If it is a predicate means it is a property name that `orderBy` will then get value from that property to use in `sort()`

Comment: @charlietfl So there is no way to sort the way I need to?